# sending mail from command line: Null message body

Tags: command-line, bash, email, pipe

I'm somehow unable to get my head around this. I am sending mails from commandline with help of a little script. But the line

```
echo 'LOREM IPSUM' | mail -s 'SUBJECT' -a 'From:TEST' < /root/recipients.txt
```

somehow seems to be wrong. The mail gets sent but without any text in it and I get the error

```
mail: Null message body; hope that's ok
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to redirect `mail`'s stdin from two sources at once:

1. First you have `echo | mail`, which binds echo's stdout to mail's stdin (via pipe), replacing the default stdin (terminal);
2. Then you have `mail < recipients.txt`, which binds the file to mail's stdin, replacing any previous redirections.

The important bit being, *it does not combine both inputs.* If you need to do that, use some combination of `cat` and command grouping:

- `(cat recipients.txt; echo 'Hello world') | mail -s ...`
- bash-only: `cat recipients.txt <(echo 'Hello world') | mail -s ...`

Although in this case it might be better to pass the recipient list as *command-line* arguments instead of input:

- `echo 'Hello world' | mail -s ... $(cat recipients.txt)`